# How to get tile selected with mouse?

Tags: pygame, game-development, tile, isometric

New to pygame, and game development in general.

This is my main loop and I am trying to blit just a tile selector image on top of the current tile that the mouse is pointing to by using collisionpoint detection. However, as seen in the picture, it partially select everything around the tile I am pointing at. Attached pics are examples of what happens and the selector tile I am using. I am not sure how to adjust the mouse coordinates appropriately and would love advice on what to do with it.

image_list[3] points to the image class that contains details about the selector tile.

```
def loop(display, screen, image_list, map_data):

# initialise conditions used in loop
display_mouse_coords = False
player_in_grasslands = True

font = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 13)
while True:
    display.fill(constants.COLOURS["BLACK"])
    
    # display map
    for y, row in enumerate(map_data):
        for x, tile in enumerate(row):
            if tile != 0:
                tile_rect = display.blit(image_list[tile - 1].img_surf, (150 + x * 10 - y * 10, 100 + x * 5 + y * 5))
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                
                # take the mouse position and scale it, too
                screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
                display_rect = display.get_rect()
                ratio_x = (screen_rect.width / display_rect.width)
                ratio_y = (screen_rect.height / display_rect.height)
                scaled_pos = (pos[0] / ratio_x, pos[1] / ratio_y)
                
                if tile_rect.collidepoint(scaled_pos):
                    display.blit(image_list[3].img_surf, tile_rect)
```

[image: Selector tile]

[image: What the game looks like]

Comment: You can use [`pygame.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) to detect if the mouse touches a non-transparent pixel of each tile. Don't forget to put the `Mask` detection inside of a `rect` collision detection for example, otherwise this could lead into some `IndexError`s.

Comment: @D_00 Do you have an example of this? The documentation is sparse for pygame.Mask, and like I said I am really new to graphics programming in general and pygame. I started looking at just building a grid that stores current map coordinates and manage this in the mouse event but if there's a way to do it without using that, I would like to know as well.

Comment: I wrote an example of this below. Take a look:

Answer (score 0):

Here are the textures that I used for this example (respectively `cursor.png`, `right.png`, `top.png`, `left.png`:

[image] [image] [image][image]

You can use the code below for a working example of [`pygame.mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html):

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Map:
    def __init__(self, width, height, origin):
        self.top_image = pygame.image.load('top.png')
        self.left_image = pygame.image.load('left.png')
        self.right_image = pygame.image.load('right.png')
        self.cursor = pygame.image.load('cursor.png')
        # create the Mask for the top image
        # (only activate when the selected pixel is non-transparent)
        self.top_image_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.top_image)

        origin[0] -= 20*width
        origin[1] += 5*height
        self.map = []
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                tile_x, tile_y = origin
                tile_x += 20*x + 20*y
                tile_y += 10*y - 10*x
                self.map.append(Tile(tile_x, tile_y))
                # draw the sides textures if needed
                if not x:
                    self.map[-1].left = True
                if y+1 == height:
                    self.map[-1].right = True

    def update(self):
        for tile in self.map:
            tile.update()

    def draw(self):
        for tile in sorted(self.map, key=lambda tile: tile.selected):
            tile.draw()

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        # make rect to check for rough collision
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 48)

        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.selected = False

    def update(self):
        self.selected = False
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint((x, y)):
            # the mask needs relative coordinates
            x -= self.rect.x
            y -= self.rect.y
            if map.top_image_mask.get_at((x, y)):
                self.selected = True

    def draw(self):
        pos = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
        screen.blit(map.top_image, pos)
        if self.left:
            screen.blit(map.left_image, pos)
        if self.right:
            screen.blit(map.right_image, pos)
        if self.selected:
            screen.blit(map.cursor, pos)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

map = Map(15, 15, [320, 100])

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((230, 250, 255))

    map.update()
    map.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60) # limit the framerate
```

Screenshot of the example:

[image]

---

It namely uses classes to store the tiles, which are generated by `Map.__init__` according to an original position, a `width` and `height` values. The code in `Map.__init__` determines the position of each tile, stored as a `Tile` object. They sometimes get the order to draw the left or right textures, to make the map look more 3D-ish.

---

But the most important part is the use of the `Map.top_image_mask` variable. This is a mask created from the `Map.top_image` [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). Its [`get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.get_at) function is used, which returns `True` if the relative point in the mask is opaque, or `False` if not. For example, with this image, `mask.get_at((0, 0))` will return `False`, because the pixel on the very top left of the image is transparent, but it will return `True` if you ask for `mask.get_at((20, 10))` for example.

I make sure to check for a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) collision before checking the mask, because calling `mask.get_at` with a point outside of the texture will return an error. The first step is then to check if the absolute mouse position collides with the rect of the texture of a specific tile, then if it "touches" it, check if the touched pixel is not transparent by the use of relative mouse coordinates and the `mask.get_at` function.

I hope that helps.